# Find multivariable function given definite integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The well known $\Gamma $ function shows that:
$$x!=\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}dt$$
This had me thinking: How can you determine $g(t,x)$ if you know that:
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty g(t,x)dt$$
Could there be an infinite, or multiple solutions depending on $f(x)$? Zero, or one? If $g$ was instead a single variable function dependent on t and we were integrating from $t=0$ to $x$, this problem would be easier; however, I don't know how this can be approached.

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of functions, for example
$$
g(t,x) = f(x)A(t) + B(t)
$$
for any functions $A$ and $B$ where $\int_0^\infty A(t) dt = 1$ and $\int_0^\infty B(t) dt = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions. For example, for any fixed $c>0$ you could take
$$g_c(t,x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{c}, & 0\leq x\leq c \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$